# Queries regarding TCP connection and TCP keep alive?

Tags: sockets, tcp

I have the following queries regarding connection and TCP keep alive:

1. Is TCP keep alive mandatory for a TCP connection?
2. Is the duration of the keep alive fixed or configurable?
3. Suppose the keep alive interval is once every 15 seconds, then is the keep alive always sent every 15 seconds or only if no application data was sent for 15 seconds?
4. How can a server (connected with a client over TCP) figure out if the connection with the client is intact or not - Can it be done using TCP keepalive- and in this case would it be the server which needs to send the keepalive? Also if keepalive is not enabled then is there any way to check the connection status other than sending an application level probe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is TCP keep alive mandatory for a TCP connection?

No, it is optional, and by RFC 1122-3 it must be off by default.

> Is the duration of the keep alive fixed or configurable?

It is required to be at least two hours by default. It is often configurable, but often only at the global level for all sockets.

> Suppose the keep alive interval is once every 15 seconds, then is the keep alive always sent every 15 seconds or only if no application data was sent for 15 seconds?

I'm not sure that this is defined, but it's hard to see how it can make a difference to you.

> How can a server (connected with a client over TCP) figure out if the connection with the client is intact or not

By observing whether it gets end of stream on receive, or ECONNRESET, or conection timeouts.

> Can it be done using TCP keepalive- and in this case would it be the server which needs to send the keepalive?

The side that needs to find out should be the side that sends the keepalives. If both, both.

> Also if keepalive is not enabled then is there any way to check the connection status other than sending an application level probe?

See above.